# Create a archive split into blocks of a maximum size using Windows shell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, compression, tar

As example. I want to compress a directory of 100GB split into 10 archives of 10GB using cmd or powershell, non-interactive without installing additional tools. Using `tar` would be awesome but something else is ok too

Most likely I want to compress into 10 individual archives which can be extracted on its own without the need to be merged back together at a later stage. Preferable first compressing 1 big file and then split it. But if this wish is hard to realize I take if for granted.

In linux I use something like this

```
tar --tape-length=2097000 -cMv --file=tar_archive.{tar,tar-{2..100}} dir1
```

But the Windows tar doesn't support `--tape-length`

How to make this work in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tool for that on Linux is PowerShell (which will require a small
learning curve for a Linux user).

See the post
[ZIP a folder of files into multiple "stand-alone" ZIP files of maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75423366/zip-a-folder-of-files-into-multiple-stand-alone-zip-files-of-maximum-size).

The answer by Minkulai contains a PowerShell script that collects files
into chunks of 50GB maximal size and zips these files into one archive.
You can modify the script for changing the size as required.

I duplicate below this script :

```
$filesFolderPath = "Path of where the PDFs are"
$archivePath = "Path to where the archive will be"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filesFolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".pdf" }
$filesToArchive = @()
$archiveSize = 0
$counter = 0

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileSize = [Math]::Round(($file.Length / 1MB), 2)
    
    # Check if the combined size of the files to be archived exceeds 50 MB
    if (($archiveSize + $fileSize) -gt 49) {
        # Create the archive if the combined size exceeds 50 MB
        $counter++
        Compress-Archive -Path $filesToArchive.FullName -DestinationPath "$($archivePath)\Archive-$counter.zip"
        $filesToArchive = @()
        $archiveSize = 0
    }

    # Add the file to the list of files to be archived
    $filesToArchive += $file
    $archiveSize += $fileSize
}

# Create the final archive if there are any remaining files to be archived
if ($filesToArchive.Count -gt 0) {
    $counter++
    Compress-Archive -Path $filesToArchive.FullName -DestinationPath "$($archivePath)\Archive-$counter.zip"
}
```

Comment: It works but it is slow and extremely heavy on resources. a 4GB folder takes hours to compress on a computer with 8GB RAM. Computer also almost freezes all the time. Possible to create standalone zips with rar or 7z console?